# Tensoflow2 LSTM - Unused parameter input_shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

So I have build Neural Network with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
tf_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
tf_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
tf_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
tf_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
tf_model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')
```

My training set is shaped as follows:

```
>> ts_train_X.shape
(16469, 3, 21)
```

I have read numerous articles and questions here on stackoverflow in order to bring the data frame in the right shape for the LSTM. Almost every of the pages I found specified the `input_shape` parameter and passed it either to LSTM(..) or Sequential(..).

When I look at the [LSTM API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) I cannot find a reference to this parameter. I also had a glimpse on the source code and to me it seems that the shape is somehow automatically inferred, but I am not sure about this.

This leads me to my question: **Why does my code work? How can the LSTM layer as the first layer know the shape of my inputs, if I don't specify the input_shape parameter?**

---

edit: change title as per suggestion in comments.

Comment: Why are you using the word "deprecated" in the question title? I think its misleading, the parameter input_shape has not been deprecated

Comment: The LSTM infers the shape of the input from... the input training data

Comment: If you have another suggestions, please tell me. I used "deprecated" because it seems to me, that the parameter was used in earlier versions, since almost every single tutorial / answer on stackoverflow uses this parameter. Yet I find no mention of it in the current documentation. Furthermore my code works. If I add the parameter, an error is thrown, since `input_shape` is not defined.

Comment: None of that means that the parameter has been deprecated. I complain because in the future, people will see your question and think that input_shape has been deprecated (which is not the case).

Comment: Then sorry for the confusion. Please tell me, what the correct description would be. I will edit the title accordingly.

Comment: Yes that looks better, see my answer on why it works, it is not about automatic inference :)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I tihnk in this case it was about automatic inference. I never explicitly passed shape information to the network, other than the training data. I just found somewhere in the docs that the `build` method is called when calling `fit`. Thus the information must be automatically infered, right?

Comment: Also I have to correct an mistake on my side. The error desribed in my above comment was due to passing the `input_shape` parameter to Sequential instead of LSTM. When passing to LSTM it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `input_shape` can be given to the constructor of any keras `Layer` subclass, as this is how the API is defined.

The code works because `input_shape` is passed as a keyword argument (the `**kwargs`), then these keyword arguments are passed by the `LSTM` constructor to the `Layer` constructor, which then proceeds to store the information for later use. This effectively means that the `input_shape` parameter does not have to be defined in each layer, and it is passed as a keyword argument instead.

I think the issue is that since `keras` has been moved to `tensorflow`, the documentation might not be complete. You can find more information about the `input_shape` parameter in the [Guide to the Sequential API](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

Comment: Thank you for your pointer to Layer and to the guide, I found some useful information there. :)